# How do i approximate a "hidden" value if i only have data about which is closer from a pair of values?

Tags: r, approximation

First of all, sorry for the mess of a title, i am not sure how to formulate the problem more precisely.

Here is the problem:

I am looking for **one** value between 0 and 1, let's call it X.

The information i have are a dataframe with 3 columns. The first 2 columns are values between 0 and 1 and the third column contains information about which value is closer to X.

Here would be an example df (real dataframe contains around 1500 of these pairs)

```
value 1 | value 2 | closer to x
--------|---------|--------
  0.3   |   0.5   |   2
  0.15  |   0.8   |   1
  0.4   |   0.7   |   1
  0.5   |   0.6   |   1
  0.1   |   0.2   |   2
  0.2   |   0.5   |   2
  0.4   |   0.9   |   1
```

Is there a function or any way i can approximate what the value X is? The dataset may also contain small measurement errors, so if 99% of value-pairs would work with x=0.41 and 1% doesn't it would still be helpful.

I am thankful for any solution or just a direction of where i could find a solution. Thanks

**EDIT: To clarify: There is only one value X that all (or at least most of) the pairs in the dataframe point towards.**

Comment: How would you like to approximate these values? E.g. take your first row. The new x-value should be between 0.3 and 0.5, but it should be closer to 0.5, so the value is constrained to the fact that it has to be >0.4. But what about the range of possible values? Do you expect the predicted value to be any value between 0.4 and 0.5 with the same likelihood or do you assume a normal distribution or another distribution?

Comment: good point, i would assume every value to have the same likelyhood.

"E.g. take your first row. The new x-value should be between 0.3 and 0.5, but it should be closer to 0.5" - the value could be anything between 0.4 and 1, because every value over 0.5 is still closer to 0.5 than to 0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, just in case anyone ever has any similar problem and wants to know how i solved my problem in the end (not saying that it's a perfect solution, but good enough for what i am doing with it):

I generated the mean between the two points, as the information the paris provide is that the value X is bigger/smaller (depending on the value for "closer to x") than the mean of the pair.

```
df$mean <- (df$value1 + df$value2 )/2
```

Then i just wrote a loop that for all possible values for x in increments of 0.001 checked if that value for x would work with all possible pairs and output the number of pairs this value x fitted to.

```
xtab <- NA
for (i in 1:1000){
  valuex <- 0+0.001*i
  sumofx <- sum(df$mean[df$closertox == 2] < valuex )+
    sum(df$mean[df$closertox == 1] > valuex )
  xtab <<- rbind(xtab,c(valuex,sumofx))
}
xtab <- xtab[-c(1),]
```

then i plotted the values to get:

```
plot(xtab)
```

[image: Plot of xtab]

Using this graph and looking at the values itself i determined that the vale X was probably between 0.57 and 0.58 for my pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Creating a tyo data set
# value1 is always lower than value2
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(666)
dat <- data.frame(value1 = round(seq(0, 0.3, length.out = 10), 1),
                  value2 = round(seq(0.4, 1, length.out = 10), 1),
                  closer = round(runif(10, 1, 2), 0))

# Simply creating a random uniform variable constraint to the bounds of being closer to the value variable mentioned in "closer" and 1
dat %>%
  mutate(constraint = value2 - (value2 - value1)/2,
         min        = if_else(closer == 1, 0, constraint),
         max        = if_else(closer == 1, constraint, 1),
         new_x      = runif(10, min = min, max = max))
```

Which gives:

```
   value1 value2 closer constraint  min  max      new_x
1     0.0    0.4      2       0.20 0.20 1.00 0.57582283
2     0.0    0.5      1       0.25 0.00 0.25 0.09940414
3     0.1    0.5      1       0.30 0.00 0.30 0.24139102
4     0.1    0.6      1       0.35 0.00 0.35 0.17811408
5     0.1    0.7      1       0.40 0.00 0.40 0.25396614
6     0.2    0.7      2       0.45 0.45 1.00 0.72183845
7     0.2    0.8      1       0.50 0.00 0.50 0.14006545
8     0.2    0.9      2       0.55 0.55 1.00 0.95891966
9     0.3    0.9      1       0.60 0.00 0.60 0.47046969
10    0.3    1.0      1       0.65 0.00 0.65 0.36334806
```

If you don't want to keep the temporary columns you can de-select them in the pipeline, e.g.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(constraint = value2 - (value2 - value1)/2,
         min        = if_else(closer == 1, 0, constraint),
         max        = if_else(closer == 1, constraint, 1),
         new_x      = runif(10, min = min, max = max)) %>%
 select(-constraint, -min, -max)
```

Comment: I am not sure if i completly understand your answer.

I unterstand how you get the minimum and the maximum value and completly agree on that. But unless i am mistaken the "next step" you take is to just randomly choose a value between min and max, which is the value "new_x".

But unless i am mistaken, this "new_x" value does not take any information from any other of the pairs. This would solve the problem if there are n number of X and n is equal to the number of rows of my df.

My problem implies that there is only one value X that all pairs in my df point towards.

Comment: Ok, just ot be sure. So in the case above even if you have 1500 rows, you are only looking for one agregate new x value? And one row tells you that it probably lies between 0.2 and 1, secodn row tells you ir probably lies between 0 and 0.25 and so on. I'm not 100% sure, but I think you could then simply take the mean of all new_x values as the best estimate for this value.

Comment: In this case, the mean would be 0.4085071.

Comment: Yes, there is one Value for X that i am trying to approximate that is true for all (or at least for most) of the 1500 pairs.

I am going to try your answer and check what the mean of all "new_x" values is in my case and see if it matches what i have gathered through other means, but i am still unsure if its really that reliable.

For example in row 1 of your example df "new-x" could be anything between 0.2 and 1, which is determined randomly. Isn't this going to skew the mean of all new_x pretty heavily each time i let it run?

Comment: Well that's the restriction you provided, i.e. the value has to be closer to either value1 or value2 but isn't constrained otherwise (so the limits are either 0 or 1). Your could of course add any other constraint - if that makes sense to your data and analysis. You could also calculate a trimmed mean at the end which wouldn't take into consideration  the most extreme valies. You coudl probably also use a weighted mean etc. Long story short: I think there's not THIS ONE statistical solution/approach to your question.